# ng-model inside angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to have a two way binding inside angular directive
This is what I am doing

```
angular.module('myapp',[]),directive('mydirective', function() {
    var directive = {};
    directive.restrict = 'E';
    directive.replace = true;
    directive.templateUrl = 'mydirective.html';
    directive.scope = {
      myModel : '=',
    };
    directive.controller = function($scope){

    }

    directive.link = function($scope, $element, attrs) {

    };
  return directive;
```

my template

```
<div ng-model="name">
</div>
<div ng-model="age">
</div>
```

Using the directive

I want to use name and age in my directive controller but don't want to map these model to parent model
I want to perform some logic on these models and then I want to set parent model.

Comment: Everyone is so eager to markdown.
There isn't anyone to answer this.
I have been struggling from 5 hours

Comment: What would you like to save in the parent model?

Comment: You define 'myModel' in your scope. shouldn't you use it then like this in your template? `ng-model="myModel.name"`

Comment: I don't want to bind name and age to parent. If I use mymodel.name and mymodel.age wouldn't they be bound to parent scope

Comment: Please read your question with hindsight, and see by yourself: we don't know what the problem is and we don't know what you've tried to solve it.

Comment: @Blackhole I want to bind name and age to directive scope and use it in directive controller and not in parent scope

Comment: why do you need `ng-model` when scope is `myModel` which would be `my-model` in html?

Comment: @charlietfl I am new to angualar. I want to treat directive as a seperate component I want to perform some business logic in directive controller. As we normally using ng-model in angular app so I used ng-model

Comment: suggest you study some directive tutorials or define question with more clarity

Comment: @charlietfl can you share any link to tutorials for my use case

Comment: start by going through tutorial on angular docs site. As for `your case` you really haven't defined one

Answer (score 0):

You are already creating a new isolated scope with `scope: {myModel:'='}` where myModel points to the parent's myModel. At this time, myModel is a reference to scope.$parent.myModel, so when you're modifying scope.myModel you're also modifying scope.$parent.myModel, as you already noticed.

What you need now is a own new model in your new scope.

```
link: function(scope) {
   scope.model = angular.copy(scope.myModel); // copies all values from parent and create a new object model which you then use in your template

   scope.saveModel = function() {
       scope.myModel.age = scope.model.age;
       scope.myModel.name = scope.model.name; //saves values back to parent
   }
```

}

Your directive template should then use `model` as ng-model like:

```
<input ng-model="model.name" />
<input ng-model="model.age" />
<button ng-click="saveModel()">apply</button>
```

Comment: there is a disconnect between `ng-model` and `my-model` in your code. If use `ng-model` need to use `require` for it

Comment: @charlietfl, no, its the template of the directive, which has access to all my defined scope properties, and not the template which uses the directive.